# How to get JQuery json function to run before of javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have never used JQuery before.  I am trying to open a json file and store some of the values in a variable called points.  When my code runs, it runs the Jquery after the rest of the javascript, but I need to run it before.  Can somebody explain how the ordering of this works and how I can structure it better.

```js
var points = [];

$.getJSON("3_clusters.json", function(json){
    console.log('Starting collating points')
    for (var row=0; row<json.X.length; row++){
        points.push([json.X[row][0], json.X[row][1]]);
    }
    console.log('Finished collating points')
});

console.log("This should run after json loaded");
```

It should create the points variable, do the getJSON stuff and then output the console message.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to do it:

1. Using callback function:

```js
var getJSON = function (callback) {
    var points = [];

    $.getJSON("3_clusters.json", function(json){
        console.log('Starting collating points')
        for (var row=0; row<json.X.length; row++){
            points.push([json.X[row][0], json.X[row][1]]);
        }
        console.log('Finished collating points')

        callback();
    });

};

getJSON(function () {
    console.log("This should run after json loaded");
});
```

2. Using asynchronous function :

```js
(async function () {
    var points = [];

    var json = await $.getJSON("3_clusters.json");

    console.log('Starting collating points')
    for (var row=0; row<json.X.length; row++){
        points.push([json.X[row][0], json.X[row][1]]);
    }
    console.log('Finished collating points');

    console.log("This should run after json loaded");
}());
```

3. Using `Promise`:

```js
var task = new Promise(function (done) {
    var points = [];

    $.getJSON("3_clusters.json", function(json){
        console.log('Starting collating points')
        for (var row=0; row<json.X.length; row++){
            points.push([json.X[row][0], json.X[row][1]]);
        }
        console.log('Finished collating points')

        done();
    });
});

task.then(function () {
    console.log("This should run after json loaded");
});
```

Comment: please fix the typo in your object: `Promsie` => `Promise`